# Security concerns while loading fixtures

Tags: python, deployment, fixtures

I need to load fixtures into the system when a new VM is up. I have dumped MongoDB and Postgres. But I can't just sit in front of the PC whenever a new machine is up. I want to be able to just "issue" a command or the script automatically does it.

But a command like `pg_dump` to dump PostgreSQL will require a password. The problem is, the script that I uses to deploy these fixtures should be under version control. The file that contains this password (if that's the only way to do automation) will not be committed. If it needs to be committed, the deploy repository is restricted for internal developers only.

My question is... what do you consider a good practice in this situation? I am thinking of using Python's `Popen` to issue these commands.

Thanks.

I also can put it in the cache server... but not sure if it's the only "better" way...

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the user that loads the fixture the privileges to write on the database regardless which way you are going to load the data.

With Postgres you can give login permission without password to specific users and eliminate the problem of a shared password or you can store the password in the pgpass file within the home directory.

Personally I find fabric a very nice tool to do deploys, in this specific case I will use it to connect to the remote machine and issue a `psql -f 'dump_data.sql' -1` command.

Comment: Ah. Yes. I actually do have fab for other things. What is the -1 doing? Is it better than `pg_restore`? And without password? Isn't that a big security issue? Thanks.

Comment: -1 wraps it in a transaction. speaking about security, you still have to be able to log as that user in order to issue to query :) that does not sound as unsafe to me.